# Terminating wall perpendicular to an unfinished outside wall

Tags: drywall, framing, moisture

I have unfinished framing that runs perpendicular to an outside wall, which is a cinder block foundation.

I think terminating drywall against another surface (such as wood or brick) which is interior you'd figure using a tear-away bead to finish the edge.

The frame will also contain Rockwool Safe'n'Sound for noise isolation, as the room I'm enclosing contains the furnace.

The question I have is how to deal with the fact it terminates against an outside wall and ensure moisture doesn't ruin the finished product (the drywall and insulation).

The framing is not load bearing, so I can replace the stud against the exterior wall if need be.

[image: Framing against exterior wall]

Comment: Does the cinder block sweat on the inside? It's painted, which will provide some separation from the blocks so they won't eat the wood. You could paint the back of the 2x4 with RedGard or something if there is concern about rot. Same with base of wall, which should be pressure treated anyway. I don't see how the insulation would be affected here.

Comment: I haven't seen it sweat or have any visible moisture on the wall in the 2 years I've lived here.  My thinking was although it may not be visible or problematic for the 2x4s, it may be a problem for drywall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always use pressure treated lumber anytime, anywhere it comes in contact with concrete. Just assume the concrete will wick water through (no matter what kind of waterproofing/drainage system may be outside) and play it safe.

For the drywall, use J-bead to wrap around the edge of the drywall where it butts up against the concrete. Though they make it in metal, you'll want to use a plastic version. This will put a layer of plastic between the edge of the drywall and the CMU wall and that should be sufficient to protect it from any moisture coming through the wall for many years to come.

Drywall J-bead:

[image: Image of a plastic drywall J-bead]
<sup>Source: [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/ClarkDietrich-1-2-in-x-10-ft-Vinyl-J-Bead-1-2-VLJB-10/311364896) no recommendation of vendor or brand implied or intended</sup>

You slip the J-bead over the edge of the drywall *before* putting the piece up against the CMU wall. It can be attached with spray adhesive, screws through the back, staples through the back, or just a few dabs of joint compound. Do this on the pieces that abut the exterior wall both inside and outside the new wall. Once it's on, you simply mud up to the edge as though there was an inside corner bead there. The J-bead has a slight rise on the edge so that you can mud it flat across the taper (if you use the tapered edge of the drywall), or it will squeeze flat if you put it on a non-tapered edge.

Rockwool, literally made out of stone, won't be impacted by any moisture that comes through the CMUs. It could, however, wick moisture to the inside of the drywall or next stud over. *However*, you're going to have a PT stud up against the wall, and that should do a pretty good job of keeping the water away.

Comment: Thank you for the info, the J-Bead and pressure treated 2x4s sounds like a very pragmatic solution.